# do you put "doing" with "efforts" or another word?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, sentence-construction, word-meaning, word-request

> I can't be more thankful to all the efforts you have been doing

My question is: in that sentence, does **doing** make sense? or I should use another word?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Doing an effort" is not correct. You **do** some work and you **put** some effort into doing the work.

The idiomatic phrase to use here is [make an effort](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/make-an-effort?q=make%20an%20effort).

> I can't be more thankful **for** all the efforts you have made.

Note that I have also changed **to** to **for**. You are thankful **to** somebody **for** what they have done.